# xgboost parameters - how can we use max.depth parameter with binary:logistic objective

Tags: r, classification, boosting

I'm new to xgboost package and here is the [doc](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md) on the parameters of this library for your reference.

My question is, logistic regression **doesn't do** binary splitting and build a tree unlike decision trees. If so, why max.depth and eta (learning rate) has been used in the [example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171043/how-to-tune-hyperparameters-of-xgboost-trees) where the objective parameter is binary:logistic. (and the answer is accepted)

Isn't it wrong combination? or am I missing anything?

```
# xgboost fitting with arbitrary parameters
xgb_params_1 = list(
  objective = "binary:logistic",                                               # binary classification
  eta = 0.01,                                                                  # learning rate
  max.depth = 3,                                                               # max tree depth
  eval_metric = "auc"                                                          # evaluation/loss metric
)
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Regardless of what kind of regression you're doing, binary or otherwise, the point of XGBOOST is to combine multiple inferences from multiple trees. The loss function is logistic in your case: http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model.html

Comment: @AlexR. thx, I just edited the question a bit. The point here is, logistic regression s being used in the boosting alg. So how come the tree related parameters are being passed.

Answer (score 1):

Boosting to minimize binomial loss indeed *does* use decision trees as weak learners (though it doesn't *have* to, it's just the most popular choice).

Logistic regression looks like this

$$ E[y \mid x] = \text{logit} \left( \sum_j \beta_j x_j \right) $$

where $\text{logit}$ is the usual logistic transformation.  For a booster the model form is

$$ E[y \mid x] = \text{logit} \left( \sum_j t_j(x) \right) $$

where each $t_j$ is a decision tree.

This model is fit by writing the binomial deviance as a function of the *linear predictor* instead of the predicted probability (which is replaced by a sum of decision trees in the boosting framework), and then boosting to minimize that loss function.  Only at the end, when making predictions, is $\text{logit}$ reapplied to get probabilities.